# adding row names to heatmap using heatmaply

Tags: heatmap, heatmaply

I am drawing a heat map of some gene expression in Rstudio, but the row names (which should be samples or gene names) are replaced by numbers. I have checked [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226420/row-labels-not-showing-in-heatmap-using-heatmaply) but no chance. sorry if it is a simple question or duplicate,  I am new in R.

Here is my R script:

```
###############################################################

library(heatmaply)

filename <- "TFzebra-TMM-name.matrix"

head(filename)

my_data <- read.table(filename, sep='\t', quote='', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
head(my_data)
dim(my_data)
nrow(my_data)
ncol(my_data)
row.names(my_data) <- my_data$samples
head (my_data)
my_data <- my_data[, -1]
head(my_data)
data <- my_data/rowSums(my_data)
my_matrix <- as.matrix(data) 

heatmaply(data, xlab = "Features", ylab = "Transcription Factors", 
          scale = "column",
          main = "Data transformation using 'scale'",
          margins = c(60,100,40,20))
```

NOTE:

```
> head (my_data)
    samples   J1 J2 J3    H1    H2    H3
1   zf-C2H2 0.00  0  0 0.507 0.232 0.540
2     baz2a 0.00  0  0 0.355 0.342 0.132
3    baz2ab 0.00  0  0 0.091 0.070 0.163
4    kdm5ba 0.00  0  0 1.835 0.856 1.527
5      dbpa 0.00  0  0 5.344 5.355 0.000
6 LOC555983 0.02  0  0 0.294 0.634 0.835
```

NOTE2:

```
> my_data <- my_data[, -1]
> head(my_data)
    J1 J2 J3    H1    H2    H3
1 0.00  0  0 0.507 0.232 0.540
2 0.00  0  0 0.355 0.342 0.132
3 0.00  0  0 0.091 0.070 0.163
4 0.00  0  0 1.835 0.856 1.527
5 0.00  0  0 5.344 5.355 0.000
6 0.02  0  0 0.294 0.634 0.835
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the first column to the row.names attribute (using the rownames function, yes, I know, it's not very consistent) before your remove it. That is:

```
rownames(my_data) <- my_data[, 1]
my_data <- my_data[, -1]
library(heatmaply)
heatmaply(my_data) # should now work
```